# Expert System using Drools

Tags: java, jsp, drools, expert-system

I'm in my last year and for a case study I decided to develop a **Web-based Expert System for evaluating the knowledge of Students**. I will be developing this with Java, JSP and Servlets. But I'm having a hard time `Drools` even i read the docs, and also i tried to search for video tutorials to start with `Drools`.

I tried to run the sample project of Drools in eclipse which I thought that would be printing "Hello World" at the console that seems I am wrong. The output whenever I run it is something like this `[[c`

Please guide me how to I start making rules with my application if I don't even know how to print "Hello World" with `Drools` at the console

A simple code of how would I do that will really help me a lot. I'm already 1 week stuck with this. Please help me.

Answer (score 4):

Check this blog post: http://salaboy.com/2011/06/06/drools-reteoo-for-dummies-1-intro/ 
It talk about the algorithm behind drools, but it can help you to understand how it works. 
It also show some rules and how they are evalauted. 
You don't really need that much to work with drools: 
1) Create a Kbuilder -> add your drl files
2) Create a kbase
3) Create a ksession
4) insert your facts
5) fire all rules -> If a rule evaluates to true all it's conditions it will fire.

Comment: There is a code in the rule, it is something like this System.out.println. Does this mean it will print something in the console? And how would a run the samples? Run as java application? If i did that, there is a choice dataConversion should i choose that?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [these examples on GitHub](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/drools/tree/master/drools-examples). There are simple and more complex ones, CashFlow for example seemed to be quite simple.

All of them are built with Maven, which will get you all the dependencies, do the compilation, testing and packaging the app. Simply running `mvn package` should give you a jar package which then can be executed from the command line with `java -jar <name-of-the-archive.jar>`